# Redirect traffic to another local machine requesting for a certain webpage

Tags: linux, windows, redirect, html

I need to redirect traffic, which is requesting for specified address(www.vlp.ee), to an another machine(10.251.36.5) located on my local network. The machine that handles the incoming traffic is linux based and running an apache server. The machine that has the homepage running, is windows based.

I have tried to make a apache 301 redirect, but that changes the value of the url address www.vlp.ee to the forwarded computer address 10.251.36.5. The server that handles the incoming traffic should listen to incoming requests, check for www.vlp.ee request and forward the requests to 10.251.36.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_proxy module for it also called reverse proxy, and you can also use ProxyPreserveHost directive for retaining the original url.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker